# Error regarding binary XML file

Tags: android

I am getting an error in the log cat regarding "binary XML file. Error inflating class fragment". Can anyone please tell me why does this occur? i am getting this for all projects in the workspace..

Comment: Underneath in logcat there should be another "caused by" exception that gives you more details on what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Can you paste the complete log here ?  or go the line of XML file where it is pointing to , it points to one of the beginning of the view which has error or in that view there might be wrong parameter used. Paste your both log and XML file.